# Was the use of Acacias for the Ark and Tabernacle more than practical?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, ark-aron-kodesh

I know of the story that Yaakov planted Acacias (Hebrew: שיטים) specifically for the future construction of the tabernacle, ark, altars and showbread table. I've also found [a write-up on acacias](http://ww2.odu.edu/~lmusselm/plant/bible/acacia.php) that  discusses their availability in the Sinai desert, their density, and their resistance to decay (making it an efficient building material).

Regardless of where the Acacias were procured from, was there a reason for their use that goes beyond just being a practical material to build from?

Comment: Your inclusion in the question of the original Hebrew that you've translated "acacia" may help people find an answer. If you don't know the Hebrew, then perhaps cite how you know acacia was used in the tabernacle.